# What will be probability of no a value without any distribution in a range?

Tags: normal-distribution, regression

A regression equation of $Y=100+20X$ at which observation is made on $x=5$ for which $Y=200$. No distribution of $Y$ is specified although Regression equation is assumed to follow normal but here in this case we have to assume $Y$ without any distribution. What will be the exact probability of $Y$ to fall between $195$ to $205$?

Comment: You could do this if you knew the mean and standard deviation of X

Comment: X is generally assumed to be a constant for linear regression - you need a distribution for Y or $\epsilon$.

Comment: Actually the error term is not  introduced here(it was introduced in the later phase of the problem). So without error term can I assume that Y is also a constant and it's  exact value within a range should be 1 in this case?